# System wide NuGet Packages

Tags: nuget

Is there a way to install NuGet Packages System wide, or do I have to install every package for every project? I am working in a restricted Environment and Need to ask the Support to install Software. Thank you in advance.

Comment: NuGet is used during compilation after build result doesn't need NuGet. You can install a nuget repository to put only validated artecfacts on it.

Comment: If you want to use Entity Framework for instance. You Need to install the Entity Framework NuGet Package. It has nothing to do with compilation.

Comment: What do you classify as installing software? You can setup a folder on your machine with packages you need. You would still need to add them into any new project you created. This would not install them in the traditional sense of installing software but add them to your project in its solution packages directory and modify the project's references. Otherwise you are left with including the packages with your source code so they are not installed anywhere.